# What is a woman who make a lot of fuss but does little or nothing called?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

According to a web log article, titled "[Weird Words Starting With 'M'](http://www.squidoo.com/weird-words-starting-with-m)", published on Squidoo, the "word" *maulifuff* means:

> maulifuff n. a woman with little energy, a fussy female who does
>   little or nothing

Thus, I'm looking for an English word or expression meaning "a woman who make a lot of fuss but does little or nothing."

Frankly, after some searches and after having verified that Merriam-Webster Dictionary and MacMillan Dictionary don't have that entry (malifuff), I surrendered, and, now, I'm not able to search something that can help me to solve the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Dilly-dally was the first that came to my mind: _to waste time by loitering or delaying_ - A diddling dilly-dally

Comment: To describe the act rather than the actor, you could say [tempest in a teapot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tempest_in_a_teapot)

Answer (score 10):

A *[fussbudget](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fussbudget)* is “One who complains or fusses a great deal, especially about unimportant matters; a [fusspot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fusspot)”.  (Note, it doesn't denote the sex of the person.)

A specifically-female term, but with strong overtones of stridency, is *[virago](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/virago#Noun)*, “Given to undue belligerence or ill manner at the slightest provocation; a shrew, a termagant” or “scolding, domineering, highly opinionated; a fishwife, a nag”.  Also see *[shrew](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shrew#Noun)* and *[fishwife](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fishwife#Noun)* (both female) and *[termagant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/termagant#Noun)* (of either sex).

Comment: +1 I actually like *fussbudget* better than mine. A term I heard a lot from my grandmother's generation.

Comment: +1 for virago, shrew and termagant. Wonderful words but they seem to have disappeared from contemporary diction. I was thinking of an apt term for someone and you just provided it.

Comment: For adjectival forms (rather than nouns) consider [*high-maintenance*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/high-maintenance) and various  less-related synonyms like *demanding, challenging, exacting, difficult, needy*.

Answer (score 5):

You could consider *[drama queen](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drama-queen)*

> (informal) a person who tends to react to every situation in an overdramatic or exaggerated manner

While there is a gender reference in the phrase, the term can be applied to either sex.

If having *little energy* is an essential part of your concept, this probably doesn't apply.  Drama queens generally display a great deal of energy, but often little in the way of accomplishment.

Comment: _Drama queen_ isn't bad; I was on the verge of suggesting [_high-maintenance_](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/high-maintenance), but I'll just leave it here as a comment. It, too, can apply to either men or women.